# XNA: How to write to a texture using shaders

Tags: xna, shader

Hey, I want to make a falling-sand-animation (powder-game, pyrosand, wxsand...) with shaders for practise.

To do so, I need an array of bytes (256x256) stored in a texture, every frame, this array is modified according to a set of rules (a simple for loop with some ifs in it).

Up to now I locked the texture, applied the rules and unlocked it every frame, but this seems to overhelm my cpu, so is there a way to modify (read, then write) a texture with shaders?

Any suggestions or tutorial-links are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [RenderTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976073.aspx) ... you can easily use a shader to draw to a texture, and then do whatever you'd like with that texture.

One thing to keep in mind is that you'll have to change your algorithm. writing shaders is an exercise in [functional programmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)g, where it sounds like you wrote it [imperatively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming)